# Linq select where has at least one entry in another table

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following structure that I wan't to query using Linq, specifically Linq to Entities (Enitity Framework).

- Table1: RouteMeta
- Table2: SitePage

Multiple **SitePages** can link to the same **RouteMeta**.

I'm querying the Route Meta to select a number of rows. I'm using a generic repository, currently like this:

```
return r.Find().ToList();
```

There's nothing special about it - the **Find** method accepts an optional linq expression, so I could do something like this:

```
return r.Find(x => x.Status=1).ToList();
```

However, what I actually want to do is to select rows from RouteMeta where at least one linked row exists in SitePages with a property IsPublished = true.

```
return r.Find(x => x.SitePages("where y => y.IsPublished = true");
```

Obviously, the above isn't correct, I'm just trying to explain the scenario better.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like 
`return r.Find(x=>x.Sitepages.Any(y=>y.Published))`?

I'd also suggesting using a profiler if possible to check that this translates properly into SQL.  It probably should do but it depends on how your repository works.

Comment: Thanks for that - I was trying to use a .Contains and couldn't get any form of syntax to work for me. Duh. Thanks for the fast solution.